# Silverlight Binding Question

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

HI All,

I am trying out my hand with Silverlight for the first time and I have a question regarding binding. I have a form that is bound to a custom data object. On that for I have two boxes labelled as such:

Driving Experiece [Textbox] years [Textbox] months.

I need to bind this to a single integer property of DrivingExperienceMonths. So for instance, if the DrivingExperienceMonths is equal to 29, I would see 2 in the years textbox and 5 in the months text box.

I can of course add a listener to the text changed events for the text boxes and handle it that way, but everything else on the form is using TwoWay binding, and I was hoping this could as well.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in WPF by implementing an `IMultiValueConverter`, but unfortunately, this isn't supported in Silverlight.

The best option is often to have your ViewModel handle this.  It could create a "Months" and a "Years" property which automatically synchronizes to your DrivingExperienceMonths value.

If you want to just use OneWay binding (just for display), two `IValueConverter`s could be used.  By for `TwoWay` databinding, it will have to be handled in code.

Comment: One a side note, some third party tools like devexpress do support multibinding.  Also here is a blog where you can download extensions that allow you to do multibinding http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/ .

Answer (score 0):

I would create a value converter (class derived from IValueConverter) that converts the integer to the full string.  You would then set an instance of the ValueConverter in the binding.

Comment: This will only work for one way binding, since there are two distinct values.  It's impossible to do ConvertBack with this...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that extracts the respective info from that property (specified via `ConverterParameter`)

**Edit:** As i just noticed (and Copsey noted in his answer) this is not going to work out if you need a two-way binding. Better do conversion in two separate properties...

Something like this:

```
public int DrivingExperienceMonths { get; set; }

public int ExpMonths
{
    get { return DrivingExperienceMonths % 12; }
    set { DrivingExperienceMonths = (ExpYears * 12) + value; }
}

public int ExpYears
{
    get { return DrivingExperienceMonths / 12; }
    set { DrivingExperienceMonths = (value * 12) + ExpMonths; }
}
```